# javamail is not working. MessagingException arises

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classformaterror

I am doing following code to send a email on gmail with javamail.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("goods.ramesh","mypassword");
                }
            });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("goods.ramesh@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("goods.ramesh@yahoo.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                    "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error stacktrace :

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/MessagingException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:484)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

I am not getting what MessagingException is doing and why it occurred.
Can any body help me to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong version of javaee.jar that does not contains anything.

Have a look to this post: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/

M.

Comment: However build is successfull. my latest netbeans 7.1.2 shows no any error as red bulbs in the editor. But after running i get stacktrace error. I am actually using Netbeans and importing the "Java ee 6 api" librariy and it provides all the importing classes required. Yet error is there. Is 'java ee 6 api' is a wrong one to use.?

Comment: the issue is that the jar contains the method signatures, but not the code of it. public void method(Object o) {/* nothing here */} . So it compiles but you won't be able to run it because the code is missing. Try with this one: http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/

Comment: I tried this jar but it doesn't work, finally I down javamail from the official site and add jars to classpath ,here is the link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.7-oth-JPR

Answer (score 1):

I had the same ClassNotFound problem. I have solved with following POM set-up

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>            
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have used this version of *glassfish-embedded-all* in my EJB UnitTesting, so my understanding is that this jar contains all classes required by Java EE API